# Regex to validate numbers before and after decimal excluding comma

Tags: regex, validation, matching

I am trying to validate decimal number of 13 digit before and 4 digit after dot excluding comma , i.e comma shouldn't be counted as a digit.

**Valid Cases**

```
1,234,567,890,123.1234

1234567890123.1234

123456789012.1234

1234567890123.123

12345.123

1.2

0
```

**In Valid Cases**

```
12345abc.23 // string or special characters  not allowed

1,234,567,890,1231.1234

1,234,567,890,123.12341

12345678901231.1234

1234567890123.12341
```

**Current Regex**

```
^[0-9]{1,13}(\.[0-9]{0,4})?$
```

The current `Regex` is counting comma as a digit.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert what is directly on the right is not 14 times a digit before matching a dot:

```
^(?!(?:[^.\s\d]*\d){14})-?\d+(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what follows is not

  - `(?:[^.\s\d]*\d){14}` Match not a digit, whitespace char or dot 14 times
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d{1,3})*` Match comma, 1-3 digits and repeat 0+ times (Or use `\d+`)
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?` Optional part, match a dot and 1-4 digits
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Ae6L1/1)

Comment: Thanks, works fine for 10 digit before and 3 digit after dot, but I changed to to validate 13 digit before and 4 digit after dot, as below , but doesn't work for input `9,999,999,999,999.1234`. ?

Comment: @stom You can extend the last quantifier to `{1,4}` like `^-?(?!(?:[^\D\S.]*\d){11})\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$`

Comment: Change to `^-?(?!([^\D\S.]*\d){14})\d+(?:,\d{4})*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$` , doesn't work , why ?

Comment: Now i want validate 13 digit before and 4 digit after dot. i.e this is valid : `9,999,999,999,999.1234` Shall i update the question ?

Comment: @stom I have updated my answer for 11 digits. Do you mean like `^(?!(?:[^.\s\d]*\d){14})-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,4})?$` See https://regex101.com/r/YUP41E/2

Comment: This doesn't work for `9,999,999,999,99.1234` i have updated the question with valid and in valid cases, kindly check.

Comment: @stom In that case you could change the quantifier from `{3}` to `{1,3}` https://regex101.com/r/1Ae6L1/1 or use `\d+` instead https://regex101.com/r/1Ae6L1/2

Comment: Great, it worked, Thank you so much , appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the optional count of , Like

```
^[0-9]{0,1}([,])?[0-9]{0,3}([,])?[0-9]{0,3}([,])?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{0,3})?$
```